# Chrome issue : "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT "

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tomcat, https

I tried to access my web application via HTTPS. It fails to load JavaScript files and shows **"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT".** But it is working as expected in IE and Firefox. It is also working fine in Chrome via HTTP.

Comment: Are you using a proxy? It seems Chrome has some issues with that: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=57255

Comment: No.. I'm not at all using any proxy..

Comment: I have the same issues since today on my web app. Some resource failed to load on HTTPS. If i copy paste the url of the resource in a new tab, it's load normally...

Comment: I know this is an old question but I think it is a CRoss Domain issue.

Comment: It very well could be a 'Same Origin Policy' issue, meaning attempting to access resources(usually scripts) in a domain from another separate one. Recently when I have seen this issue however, it has been specified as such in the debugger console. This could just be a recent update but there is much more information needed regarding this question(at least for me). Does the domain that hosts your web app have an SSL certificate? It is possible the other browsers have a fallback when requesting HTTPS if not available use HTTP, but chrome has a boner for security so they may not have allowed it.

Answer (score 3):

I started having this problem after installing the latest release of chrome 46.0.2490.80 m in an attempt to solved my previous problem of chrome displaying garbage on some sites or documents.
in my case it happens on jquery load calls.  I tried to reinstall from scratch, but could not resolve the issue.  I am running a local development wamp server.
For now I circumvented the problem by not using jquery. By the way the jquery calls have no problems in IE.