# $(selector).html(large data) can not display

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, performance, response

I'm using Jquery ajax to retrieve large data on response so i use

```
$("#id").html(data);
```

on ajax success this is not working in chrome, chrome going to stuck every time, what is wrong with this code

this is my ajax request

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url+filename,
        data: "action=searchPaging&page="+page+"&updatedFrmName="+updatedFrmName+"&scol="+scol+"&sorder="+sorder+"&totRecords="+totRecords+"&rowsPerPage="+rowsPerPage+"&"+str,
        success: function(data){
            $("#"+updatedDiv).html(data);
            if($('#goTop').length > 0) {
                $('#goTop').hide();
            }
        }
});
```

got an error in net-panel of developer tools in chrome

> net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

nothing found on google helpfull about This issue

Comment: show your ajax request plz.

Comment: ....and relevant html too! :)

Comment: Also add how large your data is.

Comment: response is a large html table with 200 records

Comment: give your ajax request `dataType:"html"`

Comment: @Kartikeya its not necessary by default it is `html`. And its `dataType` not `datatype`.

Comment: @ShailendraSharma..What is the value of updatedDiv?

Comment: have you seen ajax request in **firebug -> net(tab)**, how much data received

Comment: @ShailendraSharma Check this in your success callback alert($("#"+updatedDiv).length); and alert(data);

Comment: alert & console.log working fine

Comment: Is your `updateDiv` is visible?

Comment: yes it is already  display:block

Comment: Arjun Abhynav i have checked in firebug it's 200 kb

Comment: This question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589120/jquery-and-appending-large-amounts-of-html

Comment: @DavidJones in your given question people are discussing about generate html at client side , but in my case html is already generated at server side

Comment: Sorry I should elaborate, maybe if the returned HTML is too big you  could pass back the data and generate the html in your javascript appending it in chunks or return an array of sections of html then loop through in your javascript and append each section.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695079/chrome-issue-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-connection-timed-out  This is what i found on stack-overflow related to this issue

Comment: i have fixed this issue by added a setTimeout{} with 500 limit but root cause is still missing (: